# Camel Netty 2.11.2 component stale connection issue, not serving any requests

Tags: sockets, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I am using Camel Netty for full duplex communication over TCP socket.
My application is using the following parameters in the route.

```
<inOut uri="netty:tcp://{{IP-Port}}?   
     textline=true&amp;sync=true&amp;decoderMaxLineLength=1000000&amp;autoAppendDelimiter=false&amp;disconnect=false&amp;producerPoolMaxActive=-1&amp;producerPoolMinEvictableIdle=120000&amp;keepAlive=false&amp;noReplyLogLevel=INFO&amp;serverExceptionCaughtLogLevel=INFO&amp;requestTimeout=2500" />
```

The netty component above receives requests from a preceding wiretap in the flow.

During the day after about 8-10 hours, some of the connections show as ESTABLISHED state but will not be serving any requests. Even at the server end, these connections show as ESTABLISHED but there is no activity for hours.

When we looked at one connection closely, found that the last request attempted (not been received by server) was writing body to endpoint and got an exception org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: xxxxx on ExchangeId: ID-xxxx). On delivery attempt: 0

Since netty is being called from wiretap, after this last request, succeeding requests are not even entertained and they are blocked in wiretap itself..

I am collecting tcpdump later tonight for more details though.

Questions:

```
1. Why is producerPoolMinEvictable NOT kicking in to clear such stale connections?

2. How do we clear these stale connections automatically without having to  
   bounce the application?

3. Is there a problem using wiretap?
```

Appreciate suggestions to resolve this issue.  Please ask for any more details needed to answer and I shall be happy to share.

Note:
    camel-netty 
    2.11.2-